# Does SSL encryption work if the certificate is assign to different host?

Tags: ssl, certificate, http, smtp, pop3

I don't know much how exactly ssl work. I have shared hosting account jcubic.pl and there is ssl certificate but it belong to hosting provider domenomania.pl and when I open web browser with address https://jcubic.pl there is warning about wrong certificate.

Does it use proper encryption if the host in url is different then on certificate? Also I use email name@jcubic.pl and the pop3 and smtp servers address is mail.jcubic.pl does pop3 and smtp (or their secure counterpart) use encryption or is it unencrypted because of different host in certificate? (my email client is configured to use SSL/TLS)

Comment: It is encrypted. But when accepting a certificate for a different host than the one you are trying to reach you have to be very careful because it might be a man in the middle attack, i.e. encrypted between client and attacker and again encrypted between attacker and server but the attacker in the middle has access to the plain data and can also modify these.

Comment: "Does it use proper encryption if the host in url is different then on certificate?" - It is an invalid certificate and the browser will treat it as such.  SSL/TLS connections through a browser with an Invalid certificates are not considered secure.

Comment: It's encrypted, but it's not secure, because anyone on the network between you and the server can man-in-the-middle you and so bypass the encryption.